# Determine where function was called from in php

Tags: php, mysql

I trying to call my method like this:

```
<?php getalluser($catid);?>
```

And there is a select query in my getalluser() method:

```
function getalluser($query)
{
  $sql = "SELECT * from user where catId='".$query."'";
}
```

In another page, I call the same method and pass user id instead of category id like so:

```
<?php getalluser($userID);?>
```

Now, how i can identify if there is a category id or a user id in $query, so I can change in my where condition base on my $query.

Comment: Are they both integers value?

Comment: Yes both are integer. Like userid = 10 or catid= 5 etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add another parameter, called from.

Options should be:

```
Users
Categories

function getalluser($query, $calledFrom = '')
{
  if ($calledFrom == 'users') {
    $sql = "SELECT * from user where catId='".$query."'";
  }
  if ($calledFrom == 'categories') {
   // SQL for fetching categories.
  }
}
```

And call the function like:

```
<?php getalluser($catid, 'users');?>
<?php getalluser($catid, 'categories');?>
```

Comment: as $calledFrom is optional in function declaration how will you default it?

Comment: $calledFrom can not take any default value except a blank. If the function gets called without the $calledFrom or making it blank, nothing should return.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [debug_backtrace function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php). With this information you'll know wich file/function called it.

Answer (score 0):

"Both are integers"
You can maybe follow kfirba hint or you can add another param defaulted to false

```
function getalluser($query, $user = "")
{
  if($user == ''){
  $sql = "SELECT * from user where catId='".$query."'";
  } else {
   // Query for users
  }
}
```

Cat call:

```
<?php getalluser($catid);?>
```

User call:

```
<?php getalluser('', $userid);?> // example with first param empty
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really wished, you could do this

```
function getUserById($id, $searctype='catId') {

    // Use this to prevent anything other than userId and catId from being entered
    $types = array("catId", "userId");
    $searchtype = (in_array($searctype, $types) ? $searchtype:"catId";

    $sql = "SELECT * from user where ".$searchtype."='".$id."'";
}
```

then call `getUserById($userId, "userId");

Note: Please look into using PDO. It's a safer way to deal with SQL & helps prevent SQL injection.